# Can't boot Ubuntu 16.04 OS

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, data-recovery, hp

It's happand after the laptop is accidently shutdown when battery is dry. Theb when I try to start the laptop it  always show blank purple screen.

So I tried to select option "advance option" then select recovery. But the terminal show this:

ubuntu busybox v1.22.1 initramfs uuid xxxxx not exist

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest booting a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media), then `fsck` [*file-system check*] your disk partition(s) to find & correct any errors (which is possibly of untidy power-off).  After this, a reboot will most likely find it back to normal.

Comment: Okay, thanks @guiverc . Can you give step by step guide for this process or any link? I'll try this after get my live usb-boot

Comment: Thank you, but not duplicate..

Comment: Look at all the answers of the duplicate @fulltimecoder : your disk just disappeared (check cables or replace disk but first follow the duplicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After strugling with tutorial around Askubuntu and from another sites unfortunately it still the same.

Then I tried to access recovery process and upstart on previous kernel version in the list on advance option page of start menu. It's working and everything accessible including the internet by command below.

`sudo nmtui`

Then from command line I remove active kernel

`sudo apt remove linux-image-x.x.x-xx-generic linux-headers-x.x.x-xx-generic`

Reinstall again the latest and perfect one of my Ubuntu version

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic`

Then reboot,

`sudo reboot`

Everything working like before in my case.

Comment: I still suspect it's related to a `fsck`.  Every 30th boot the system will force-check itself (the count can be altered but 30 is default) which achieves what I suggested.  I suggested 'live' media as it's easiest when the drive/partition is unmounted (the install-media will be mounted not your hdd/sdd) but if the 30th `fsck` wasn't your fix (which should be performed after a incorrect shutdown as your describe) you may have issues unfixed that will re-occur so I'd still suggest file-system-check be performed (*because of accidental shutdown*)